# Eclipse TFS Plugin Check/Uncheck all pending changes

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin

I'm using the Eclipse TFS Plugin ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026.aspx)).

Whenever I'm trying to Checkin pending changes all of them are deselected by default. There is no check/uncheck all button (like in Visual Studio).

I have to manually check all the boxes (which can be over 1000 files in my case) on EVERY checkin.

I've tried different key-combinations like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + Click, but can't figure this one out.

Any help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple-A (on Mac OS, substitute the select-all keyboard shortcut appropriate to your operating system) to select all files, then click the checkbox next to any of them.

Comment: >.< I can't believe I didn't try that.. Thanks

Comment: @Rob, I'd love to improve the discoverability of this - if you tell me what keystrokes you did try (or would have expected to work) then we can improve this in the future...!

Comment: Nice Edward. How about: Select some row then Shift + Click some other row (it selects all rows between) i.e. windows directory-ish-behavior. Also it might be a good idea to add a `Check` & `Uncheck` button. TortoiseSVN features this: http://i41.tinypic.com/2jep895.png

Comment: I think that multi-select (via shift-arrow, shift-click or control/command-click) and then selecting a checkbox should work...  should be the same semantics as iTunes...

Comment: Shift-click nor control/command-click are working for me. It only selects the row clicked on, not the ones between..

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure why we turned multi-select off for that table.  I'll take a look!

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out. You were right about selecting the row iTunes-ish. However, this is not possible when pressing the checkboxes, which feels more natural to me. Thanks anyway!